# How to avoid lemmatizing already lemmatized sentences of a row in pandas dataframe for speedup

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, lemmatization

**Given**:

A simple and small pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user_ip":       ["u7", "u3", "u1", "u9", "u4","u8", "u1", "u2", "u5"],
        "raw_sentence":  ["First sentence!", np.nan, "I go to school everyday!", "She likes chips!", "I go to school everyday!", "This is 1 sample text!", "She likes chips!", "This is the thrid sentence.", "I go to school everyday!"],
    }
  )

    user_ip    raw_sentence
0   u7         First sentence!
1   u3         NaN
2   u1         I go to school everyday! 
3   u9         She likes chips!
4   u4         I go to school everyday!     <<< duplicate >>>
5   u8         This is 1 sample text!
6   u1         She likes chips!             <<< duplicate >>>
7   u2         This is the thrid sentence.
8   u5         I go to school everyday!     <<< duplicate >>>
```

**Goal**:

I wonder if I could possibly avoid calling `map` or consider any other strategies for those rows with duplicated (exact similar) sentences in `raw_sentence` column. My intention is to speedup my implementation for bigger sized pandas dataframe (`~100K` rows).

**[*Inefficient*] Solution**:

Right now, I take advantage of `.map()` using `lambda` which goes through each row and call `get_lm()` function to retrieves lemmas of raw input sentences as follows:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all', quiet=True, raise_on_error=True,)
STOPWORDS = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
wnl = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

def get_lm(input_sent:str="my text!"):
    tks = [ w for w in tokenizer.tokenize(input_sent.lower()) if not w in STOPWORDS and len(w) > 1 and not w.isnumeric() ]
    lms = [ wnl.lemmatize(w, t[0].lower()) if t[0].lower() in ['a', 's', 'r', 'n', 'v'] else wnl.lemmatize(w) for w, t in nltk.pos_tag(tks)] 
    return lms

df["lemma"] = df["raw_sentence"].map(lambda raw: get_lm(input_sent=raw), na_action='ignore')

    user_ip     raw_sentence                    lemma
0   u7          First sentence!                 [first, sentence]         <<< 1st occurrence => lemmatization OK! >>>
1   u3          NaN                             NaN                       <<< ignone None using na_action='ignore' >>>
2   u1          I go to school everyday!        [go, school, everyday]    <<< 1st occurrence => lemmatization OK! >>>
3   u9          She likes chips!                [like, chip]              <<< 1st occurrence => lemmatization OK! >>>
4   u4          I go to school everyday!        [go, school, everyday]    <<< already lemmatized, no need to do it again >>>
5   u8          This is 1 sample text!          [sample, text]            <<< 1st occurrence => lemmatization OK! >>>
6   u1          She likes chips!                [like, chip]              <<< already lemmatized, no need to do it again >>>
7   u2          This is the thrid sentence.     [thrid, sentence]         <<< 1st occurrence => lemmatization OK! >>>
8   u5          I go to school everyday!        [go, school, everyday]    <<< already lemmatized, no need to do it again >>>
```

Is there any more efficient approach to fix this issue?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache):

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def get_lm(input_sent:str="my text!"):
    tks = [ w for w in tokenizer.tokenize(input_sent.lower()) if not w in STOPWORDS and len(w) > 1 and not w.isnumeric() ]
    lms = [ wnl.lemmatize(w, t[0].lower()) if t[0].lower() in ['a', 's', 'r', 'n', 'v'] else wnl.lemmatize(w) for w, t in nltk.pos_tag(tks)] 
    return lms

df["lemma"] = df["raw_sentence"].map(lambda raw: get_lm(input_sent=raw), na_action='ignore')
```

Output:

```
  user_ip                 raw_sentence                   lemma
0      u7              First sentence!       [first, sentence]
1      u3                          NaN                     NaN
2      u1     I go to school everyday!  [go, school, everyday]
3      u9             She likes chips!            [like, chip]
4      u4     I go to school everyday!  [go, school, everyday]
5      u8       This is 1 sample text!          [sample, text]
6      u1             She likes chips!            [like, chip]
7      u2  This is the thrid sentence.       [thrid, sentence]
8      u5     I go to school everyday!  [go, school, everyday]
```

Comment: `functools.cache` is just a fancy wrapper for a dictionary, but it does look cleaner.  why `lambda` though?

Comment: @QuangHoang the lambda is useless, I just copied OP's original code ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advanced solution! could you also please elaborate why `lambda` was unnecessary in my code?  You believe I could simply write `df["lemma"] = df["raw_sentence"].map(get_lm, na_action='ignore')` ?
I wonder if adding `@cache` might cause some sort of memory leakage or memory error in big dataframe size?

Comment: @Farid because you use the first parameter of your function, `df["raw_sentence"].map(get_lm, na_action='ignore')` is equivalent. Regarding memory, yes the cache will build a dictionary, but as the values are lists (mutable objects), all shared lists are actually the same in memory, not nothing extra is used. You can see this by doing `df['lemma'][2][0] = 'XXX'` and see how all lists are impacted (if this is an issue you would need to get a copy (`.map(lambda raw: get_lm(input_sent=raw).copy(), na_action='ignore')`, this would thus use more memory, N+1 for each list assuming N repeats) ;)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to run the `map` only on unique sentences in your column.

Then use that as a mapping `dict`-ionary:

```
mapper = dict(zip(df["raw_sentence"].drop_duplicates(),df["raw_sentence"].drop_duplicates().map(lambda raw: get_lm(input_sent=raw), na_action='ignore').rename("lemma")))

df["lemma"] = df["raw_sentence"].map(mapper)
```

Comment: It should be noted that in this way, all the rows with same `raw_sentence` share a copy of the lemma array, which probably is a good thing (reduced memory used). Also, it should be `mapper` on the second command.